# Save console output in txt file as it happens

Tags: python, output-buffering

I want to **save my console output in a text file**, but I want it to be **as it happens** so that if the program crashes, logs will be saved.
Do you have some ideas?

I can't just specify `file` in `logger` because I have a lot of different loggers that are printing into the console.

Comment: You can run your python program like `python foo.py 2>&1 | tee -a logfile.log`

Comment: @Jay Can't manage to make it work in pycharm but I found an option that allows to save the console, but I would like to put it directly in my python code (I want to save the console only in one endpoint call of my API)

Comment: It seems more likely that you should be using the standard python logging, instead of redirecting your console output to a text file.  This is generally preferred, because, you can set the logging level for various messages to be more verbose or concise depending on whether you are running in production mode or debug mode.  See python docs here for logging: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you indeed can use a logger, just adding a file handler, from the logging module you can read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook)

As an example you can use something like this, which logs both to the terminal and to a file:

```
import logging
from pathlib import Path

root_path = <YOUR PATH>

log_level = logging.DEBUG

# Print to the terminal
logging.root.setLevel(log_level)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
stream = logging.StreamHandler()
stream.setLevel(log_level)
stream.setFormatter(formatter)
log = logging.getLogger("pythonConfig")
if not log.hasHandlers():
    log.setLevel(log_level)
    log.addHandler(stream)

# file handler:
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(Path(root_path / "process.log"), mode="w")
file_handler.setLevel(log_level)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(file_handler)

log.info("test")
```

If you have multiple loggers, you can still use this solutions as loggers can inherit from other just put the handler in the root logger and ensure that the others take the handler from that one.

As an alternative you can use nohup command which will keep the process running even if the terminal closes and will return the outputs to the desired location:

```
nohup python main.py > log_file.out &
```

Comment: that is also best practice

Comment: The `& >` syntax is not standard POSIX `sh`, though; you want `nohup python main.py >log_file.out 2>&1` if you put this in a `cron` job, for example, where Bashisms are not available. (Also, weird to put a space between `&` and `>`)

Comment: @tripleee, right thanks, that "& >" was a typo I have just edited it. The point on the & at the end is just to allow the user to continue using the terminal, is not really needed

Answer (score 4):

There are literally many ways to do this. However, they are not all suitable for different reasons (maintainability, ease of use, reinvent the wheel, etc.).

If you don't mind using your operating system built-ins you can:

- forward standard output and error streams to a file of your choice with `python3 -u ./myscript.py 2>&1 outputfile.txt`.
- forward standard output and error streams to a file of your choice AND display it to the console too with `python3 -u ./myscript.py 2>&1 tee outputfile.txt`. The `-u` option specifies the output is unbuffered (i.e.: whats put in the pipe goes immediately out).

If you want to do it from the Python side you can:

- use the `logging` module to output the generated logs to a file handle instead of the standard output.
- override the stdout and stderr streams defined in sys (`sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`) so that they point to an opened file handle of your choice. For instance `sys.stdout = open("log-stdout.txt", "w")`.

As a personnal preference, the simpler, the better. The `logging` module is made for the purpose of logging and provides all the necessary mechanisms to achieve what you want. So.. I would suggest that you stick with it. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) is a link to the `logging` module documentation which also provides many examples from simple use to more complex and advanced use.