# Logging to different file everyday

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Building on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74516445/10538013) answer by @Ziur Opla, Is it possible to put this on a per day basis? Meaning one day log to `12-16-2023.log` then the next day log to `12-17-2023.log` and so on? I havent had any luck with this it creates the file but will still write to the original.

```py
import logging as log
import sys
from datetime import datetime

log_file = f'{datetime.now().strftime("%m.%d.%Y")}.log'
log_fh = log.FileHandler(log_file)
log_sh = log.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
log_format = f'[{datetime.now()}] %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
# Possible levels: DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL    
log_level = 'INFO' 
log.basicConfig(format=log_format, level=log_level, 
     handlers=[log_sh, log_fh])

log.info('test text)

log_file = f'{datetime.now().strftime("%m.%d.%Y")}.log'

log.info('next day test text')
```

It's gotta be possible right? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718204/python-how-to-create-log-file-everyday-using-logging-module) confuses me..

Comment: did you read documentation for `logging`? As I remeber `logging` has functions to rotate files.

Comment: if you run code all time then it can't run again `f'{datetime.now().strftime("%m.%d.%Y")}.log'` to create new filename.

Comment: see documetation for [logging handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#module-logging.handlers) and part about [TimeRotatingHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler)

Comment: I don't understand what it the problem. You have to use `TimeRotatingHandler` instead of `FileHandler`. If you get error message then show it in question (not in comments) as text (not image)

Comment: changing date in variable `log_file` can't change this value in already existing `FileHandler()`. It may need to change some value inside `log_fh`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing date in variable `log_file` can't change this value in already existing `FileHandler()`.
It needs to change value inside `log_fh`

See source code for [FileHandler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1202)

In `__init__` you can see `self.baseFilename = os.path.abspath(filename)` so you can do

```
log_fh.baseFilename = os.path.abspath(new_filename)
```

But there is other problem. Handler keeps old file still open and it still write to old file.
But handler has also function `.close()` and it helps.

This works for me:

```
log_fh.baseFilename = os.path.abspath(new_filename)
log_fh.close()
```

It will automatically open new file with new filename when you send new info to log.

---

If you don't have access to `log_fh` then you can use `log.getLogger().handlers` to get list with all handlers and you have to check which one is a `FileHandler`

```
for handler in log.getLogger().handlers:
    if isinstance(handler, log.FileHandler):
        handler.baseFilename = os.path.abspath(new_filename)
        handler.close()
```

---

But `logging` has special handler [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) to change filename.

I think you need

```
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

log_trfh = TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename, when='D', interval=1)
```

and it changes file every day.

And it automatically adds `%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S` to old file - so you can use filename without date.

To test it you would need to change date in system.
Or test with `when="M"` to get new file every minute.

---

It seems it add date to old file when it doesn't have extension `.log`

---

Full working code which I used for tests:

```
from datetime import datetime
import logging as log
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import os
import sys


log_file = f'{datetime.now().strftime("%m.%d.%Y")}.log'

log_fh = log.FileHandler(log_file)
log_trfh = TimedRotatingFileHandler('time_rotating', when='M', interval=1)
log_sh = log.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)

log_format = f'[{datetime.now()}] %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
# Possible levels: DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL    
log_level = 'INFO' 
result = log.basicConfig(format=log_format, level=log_level, 
     handlers=[log_sh, log_fh, log_trfh])

# -----

#print(log_fh.baseFilename)

log.info('test text')

# -----

filename = 'test2.log'
log_fh.baseFilename = os.path.abspath(filename)
log_fh.close()

log.info('next day test text')

# -----

filename = 'another.log'

for handler in log.getLogger().handlers:
    if isinstance(handler, log.FileHandler):
        handler.baseFilename = os.path.abspath(filename)
        handler.close()

log.info('another day test text')
```

Comment: Using `TimedRotatingFileHandler` is the correct thing to do, so I think this should be further up in your answer. The first method you mentioned *does work*, but isn't recommended.

Comment: @blueteeth I agree that `TimedRotatingFileHandler` should be preferred method. I started digging in problem with `FileHandler` so I wrote it at first, and little later I start checking `TimedRotatingFileHandler` so i add it later :) So answer shows I was working.